# jqgrid validation before showing form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to check before showing add form in `jqgrid` that variable `myVar` has value. Following is my code in add option to check whether `myVar` has value or not. If `myVar` is null then I don't want add form to be open.

```
}).navGrid('#mypager',{cloneToTop:true, edit:false,add:true,del:false,view:false,search: false,refresh:true},
    {},
    {
    beforeShowForm : function (formid)
    {
        if(myVar.length==0)
        {
            alert("Value can't be blank!");
            return[false,"Value can't be blank!"];
        }
    },
    recreateForm: true,
    reloadAfterSubmit:true,
    closeOnEscape:true, 
    modal:true,
    jqModal: false,
    savekey: [true,13],
    width:550,
    mtype:'POST',
    url: 'MyServlet',
    editData:{action:'ListInsert',myVar: function () {return myVar;}},
    afterSubmit: function (response)
    {
        var myInfo = '<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">'+'<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" '+'style="float: left; margin-right:.3em;"></span>'+ response.responseText +'</div>';
        $infoTr = $("#TblGrid_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + ">tbody>tr.tinfo"),$infoTd = $infoTr.children("td.topinfo"); 
        $infoTd.html(myInfo);
        $infoTr.show();
        return [true, "", ""];                  
    },
    errorTextFormat: function (response)
    {
        return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" ' +'style="float:left; margin-right:.3em;"></span>' +response.responseText;
    }
},
```

Above code shows the alert, but still shows the add form.
`myVar` contains id from other grid and If `myVar` doesn't have value then I don't want to show add form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more code? Would be easier to tell whats going on with your form

Comment: @Cammy I have added more code to the question. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I didnt realized you were using a framework. But I checked the documentation and didnt find anything that says you can abort the showing of the rest of the form in the 'beforeShowForm'. Or that it can have a return value -> return[false,"Value can't be blank!"];
maybe reconsider this line

Comment: You could close the form yourself: `if(!myVar){$('#btCancel').click(); alert('...')}` where btCancel is the cancel button of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can't deny opening of Add/Edit form by returning some value from `beforeShowForm`. What you can do is closing of the form immediately after opening. You can use `afterShowForm` for example. The code could be something like

```js
afterShowForm: function () {
    var idSelector = $.jgrid.jqID(this.p.id);
    if(myVar.length==0) {
        $.jgrid.hideModal("#editmod" + idSelector, {gbox: "#gbox_" + idSelector});
        alert("Value can't be blank!");
    }
}
```

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DenyEditFormOpening.htm).