# do not show the Edit form using beforeShowForm function jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have the following code

```js
editOptions: {
    beforeShowForm: function () {
        var myGrid = $('#list'),
        selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
        IsIssued = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'Status');
        // alert(IsIssued);
        if (IsIssued == 'true') {
            alert("asd")
            return [false];
        }
        else
            return [true, "ll"];
    },
```

I want that if the

`(IsIssued == 'true')`

then do not show the Edit Form. Is it possible? Because it is always showing me the Edit form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19634197/315935) describes how you can close Add/Edit form directly after it will be opened. You can use either `beforeShowForm` or `afterShowForm` in the same way because both have no direct way to deny opening of the form.

In my opinion you should consider other options which could be more understandable from the point of view of the user. You can disable Edit button of the navigator bar on selection of rows which should be not editing. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EdableDisableEditDelNavigatorButtons.htm) from [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376355/315935) demonstrates the approach. Alternatively you can hide Edit button on selection of the rows which should be non-editable. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideShowNavGridButtonsDynamically.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057838/315935) demonstrates this.

Comment: thanks Oleg.It works and i have been searching for you before.Could u please look at my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630241/jqgrid-multiselect-column-loading-data-from-server

Comment: @janina: You are welcome! Sorry, but I'm busy now - I have to do my main job. :-) Probably later...

Comment: Ok...But please look at it later.I think only you can solve that problem